# Limitar el numero de caracteres mostrados en tabla html?

Tags: html, laravel, html-tabla

Hola estoy haciendo un crud con un texto extenso en una de las columnas del index, hasta aquí todo bien si no fuera porque se muestra demasiado texto en esta columna y me gustaría limitar un poco el texto ya que está la opción show del crud donde se enseñaría todo el texto.
Hay alguna form de limitar el numero de caracteres mostrados en un td ?? se puede con html? o javascript o algo similar? He estado viendo lo de limitar caracteres en los inputs y todo esto pero, yo no necesito limitarlo aquí ya que necesito que el usuario pueda escribir un largo texto. Pero a la hora de mostrarlo que se acorte en algún sitio.

Comment: Agrega el codigo de lo que tienes hecho

Comment: Suponiendo que el valor que escribes en el elemento `td` corresponde al valor de una variable, podrías usar el método [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring). Claro, hay toda una lógica que aplicar para obtener un resultado correcto para los casos particulares. Todo depende de la forma en que escribes los datos en tu tabla. Si pudieras incluir un [mcve] sería lo mejor. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con una función que después llamas donde la necesites;

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('getShortedString')) {
    function getShortedString($text, $length=null)
    {
        $formatedString = ucwords($text);

        if ($length != null) {
            if (strlen($formatedString) <= $length) {
                return $formatedString;
            } else {
                $y = substr($formatedString, 0, $length) . '...';
                return $y;
            }
        } else {
            return $formatedString;
        }
    }
}
```

En donde $text es el texto que quieres acortar y $lenght es el número de caracteres que quieres que se impriman;

En la vista llamarías a la función:

```
{!! getShortedString($post->content, 100) !!}
```

por ejemplo.